# How to select only a few fields using kotlin exposed?

Tags: sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have a big database of 2,600,000 records and I want to do some advanced searches on it by looping over all records. However, running a script with `selectAll()` takes a very long time to load.

As a workaround, I'm looping over 100,000 records 26 times using this code:

```
for (i in 1..26) {
    transaction {
        for (app in AppsTable.selectAll().limit(n = 100000, offset = i * 100000L)) {

            //..analysis
        }
    }
}
```

How can I speed up this query or if possible how can I reduce the query set by queries just the columns I need to work with? For eg, can I do something like this -

`AppsTable.selectAll(AppsTable.name, AppsTable.downloadCount, AppsTable.developerId)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `slice()` method before `selectAll()` like this:

```
AppsTable.slice(AppsTable.name, AppsTable.downloadCount, AppsTable.developerId)
         .selectAll()
         .limit(n = 100000, offset = i * 100000L)
```